# Rigid body not starting as deactivated

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to create an animation of two billiard balls colliding. I have been following a tutorial which uses rigid body for animations. I have placed the two spheres on a rough model of a billard table surface and enabled rigid body on both. The rigid body settings are the same for both balls, except that the one that is supposed to first move when hit by the other, has "start deactivated" and "enable deactivation.." activated. The settings for the balls as well as the table is shown in the pictures. 
[image: Settings for the second ball]

[image: Settings for the table]

The scene gravity has been put to X=0, y=20, z=-50. This seems to work in the tutorial, but when i playback the animation, both balls start moving from the beginning. I have not been able to fix this, does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Also, i am going to use this for a billiard tutorial video and want to do renders of several shots, so if you have a suggestion on a better way to do these animations, it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Why would you have any gravity on the Y axis? Also 50 *may* be too high, the default is 9.81.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this url
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu6zbf7tdoU
and go to 11:27 and see how he animated the sphere( this is really usefull i think in your simulation ;).

Comment: Notice that he animated the checkbox.

Comment: Also in the video he animated the ball location for about 15 frames.You might not want to do this because the billiard balls won't have enought time to "catch" a rotational spin while they collide with the table, instead(of 15 frames) ~2 frames would be nice (if this sounds confusing don't hesitate to ask!)

Comment: That seems to do it, thank you! It is however still a mystery to me why the "start deactivated" does not do its job. But that does not matter now that i do it in this way :)